# how to call page which creates pdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page called *OrderExport.aspx* which creates a pdf file in a folder on the server.

In my page *OrderSend.aspx* I have a function which sends an e-mail with the pdf file attached, like this:

```
Dim atc As Net.Mail.Attachment = New Attachment(stm, fileNameOrder)
mail.Attachments.Add(atc)
```

How can I call *OrderExport.aspx* from this function before sending the e-mail without showing it for the user?

I need to make sure that the pdf file exists when sending the e-mail.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's the UI here? Is there a page where the user clicks a button to create and email the PDF?

Comment: There is a button on the ASP.NET page called "Send e-mail". When clicking this button the pdf should be created first. The pdf file is created when OrderExport.aspx is run.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a class rather than an aspx page to handle the PDF creation.  One way to do this is to use the PDFSharp library which can handle creating the PDF document and then saving it to a stream which can be attach to an email message.  You could also save the stream to a file on the server at the same time.

```
' Create a new PDF document
Dim document As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
document.Info.Title = "TITLE"
Dim securitySettings As Security.PdfSecuritySettings = document.SecuritySettings
' Restrict some rights.
securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = False
securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = False
securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = False
securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = False
securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = True
securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = False
securitySettings.PermitPrint = True
' Create an empty page
Dim page As PdfPage = document.AddPage
' Get an XGraphics object for drawing
Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(imgPermit)
gfx.DrawImage(img, 20, 20)
Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
document.Save(stream, False)
Dim xStream As System.IO.Stream = stream
SendEmail(sEmail, xStream)
```

in your mail message it would be constructed similar to this

```
Dim xStream As New Attachment(pdf, "FILE" + Date.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") + ".pdf")
mm.Attachments.Add(xStream)
```

Comment: I'm using ReportViewer for creating the pdf so in this project I would prefer to stick to that. I have problems with timeouts right now when the pdf file is created only in the memory, that's the reason why I'm testing to create the pdf file on the hard drive first and then send it. Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with the syntax so I really have to ask you guys.

Comment: The syntax I listed is really independent of what library you are using.  It sounds like the pdf creation is taking too long which is why you are getting that timeout in the first place.  There may be some optimization you can do. Beyond that, you still need to put it into a class rather than an aspx page, call the class which writes to the server, then attempt to attach that file to the email

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the GUI from the actual logic.

You presumably have code in OrderExport.aspx that creates the PDF and saves it to disk. You should put that code into a separate class, so that you can call it from OrderExport.aspx, and from the page with the "Send e-mail" button. Similarly, extract the code for sending the email from OrderSend.aspx and call it from there, and from the "Send e-mail" button.

Answer (score 0):

Separation of Concerns is the best solution, but if you need a quick solution -not a good one- make the class and the function public  and call it like any other class